# Check if Sql Server Compact Database(.sdf) contains something without connecting

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, sdf

Is it possible to determine that an .sdf database contains something without connecting to it initially?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if a file is a SQL Compact database file at all by inpsecting the file header - see http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2008/04/testing-sdf-file-for-version-info.html - but otherwise no